# Android setBackground on Animation end doesn't works

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `GridView` and each item  consists from an `ImageView` and a `ΤextView` with visibility set to INVISIBLE.

GridView has a onClickListener for each item. OnItemClick I set the TextView to visible and attach a ClickListener.
Then if the user clicks on the TextView I set the bakground to GRAY, I'm doing some task on a custom AsyncTask and I'm using an Animation which I want to set the view to Invisible again and the bg color to transparent.

Because I need to reference the View in an inner class method ( onAnimationEnd() ) I assign it to a final var.
The problem is if I click the *same View for a second time in a row* the View stays visible ( doesn't goes through onAnimationEnd()  ).

The code is :

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


                child1 = getView().findViewById(position);
                child1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                child1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final View animView = v;
                    animView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);



                     SetWallpaperTask t = new SetWallpaperTask();
                     t.execute(res2);


                      AlphaAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); 
                      fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(4000);       // time for animation in milliseconds
                      fadeOutAnimation.setFillAfter(false);     // make the transformation persist
                      fadeOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {         
                          @Override
                          public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                              animView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                              animView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

                          @Override
                          public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
                      });

                      animView.setAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
                      animView.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);                         

                }

            });

         }
    });
```

Comment: First you need to clear the animation for the view, and then add new animation

Comment: @GangaNaidu how should I clear the animation ?

Comment: .clearAnimation()...before adding animation to the view